# Two way data binding in angular 12 reactive forms

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, forms, angular12

I've been using angular for a while. I want to implement two way binding but I'm stuck with the following code.

Since `[(ngModel)]` is no no longer used in angular 12 within the `formGroup` I'm unable to find a solution

```
socials = [
{ name: 'Facebook', icon: 'facebook.webp', selected: false, link:'' },
{ name: 'Instagram', icon: 'instagram.webp', selected: false, link:'' },
{ name: 'Twitter', icon: 'linkdin.webp', selected: false, link:'' },
{ name: 'Whatsapp', icon: 'whatsapp.webp', selected: false, link:'' }
```

];

here I want to change the value of link that will be entered in the following input (6th last line)

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 col-lg-3 my-2" *ngFor="let control of socialsArray.controls; let i = index;">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" (change)="getSelectedSocialsCards()" [formControl]="control" id="checkbox{{i}}">
          <label for="checkbox{{i}}" class="w-100">
            <div class="card cursorIn" [ngStyle] = "{'background-color' : socials[i].selected == true ? '#ededed' : '#fff'}">
              <div class="d-flex justify-content-end pt-2 pr-2 h-25">
                <fa-icon [icon]="faCheckCircle" [ngClass]="socials[i].selected === true ? 'iconColor' : 'iconColor1'"></fa-icon>
              </div>
              <div class="card-body d-flex p-0 px-4 mt-0">
                <div class="col-3 align-self-center font-weight-bold text-center cardIcon p-0">
                  <img src="/assets/images/social_media/{{socials[i].icon}}" width="40px" height="40px"
                    class="rounded-circle">
                </div>
                <div class="col-9 d-flex flex-column justify-content-start align-items-start cardRight">
                  <div>
                    {{socials[i].name}}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 mt-2" [ngStyle] = "{'display' : socials[i].selected == true ? 'block' : 'none' }">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>
                  {{socials[i].name}} link
                </label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" (change)="getSelectedSocialsCards()" formControlName="socialLink">
              </div>
            </div>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
```

I've declared `socialLink` inside `formGroup`

```
socialLink:new FormControl(null, [Validators.required])
```

this is my component.ts code for the same

```
getSelectedSocialsCards() {
this.selectedSocialsCards = [];
this.socialsArray.controls.forEach((control, i) => {
  this.socials[i].selected = false;
  if (control.value) {
    this.socials[i].selected = true;
    this.socials[i].link = this.addForm.get('socialLink').value;
   let linksValue = {'socialName': this.socials[i].name, 'socialLink': this.socials[i].link}
    this.selectedSocialsCards.push(linksValue);
  }
});
console.log(this.selectedSocialsCards);
this.socialError =  this.selectedSocialsCards.length > 0 ? false : true;
this.addForm.patchValue({socialsCheck: this.selectedSocialsCards});
```

}

So far I'm able to get the last value inserted intot he input field and that is the value of all the links.

I've tried to resolve the issue but couldn't find any solution. I'll be obliged if anyone can help me with this.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [(ngModel)] in within the formGroup mention 'name' in tag.
for example <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" (change)="getSelectedSocialsCards()" [formControl]="control" [(ngModel)]="testcontrol" name="testcontrol" id="checkbox{{i}}"> like that

Comment: Hi thank you so much for your help!
I had to make a minor change by replacing `name` to `formControlName` and it worked.
thanks again have a good day